# How to deselect a date upon the second click on the asp .net calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

what I have is:

PatientsSchedule.cs

```
public static List<DateTime> listDatetime = new List<DateTime>();
```

plan.aspx.cs

```
protected void CalendarMain_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
    {
        PatientsSchedule.listDatetime.Add(e.Day.Date);         
    }
    Session["SelectedDate"] = PatientsSchedule.listDatetime;
}

protected void CalendarMain_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["SelectedDate"] != null)
    {
       List<DateTime> newlist = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDate"];
       foreach (DateTime dt in newlist)
       {
           CalendarMain.SelectedDates.Add(dt);
       }
       PatientsSchedule.listDatetime.Clear();
    }
}
```

The above code is able to do multi-selection of dates however, I am trying to deselect the date by clicking one of the selected date.

Please help =)

Comment: Where do you try to deselect it? What is CalendarMain-SelectionChanged actually doing?

Comment: i tried in both CalendarMain_SelectionChanged & CalendarMain_DayRender methods but doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

When the selection changes, you (have to) know which item was clicked, so you can add or remove it from the list. In the event handler you check if the clicked item is in the list already, if so remove it. If not add it! ;)

Comment: hi, yup i did get the date value upon clicking the date, removed it from the list if it's already in the list. But doesn't work

Comment: Maybe rebind the data again to the control? Refresh client-side, server-side.